# Show remote computer status

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-teams

Im working in big organization as SW developer and my team is using 2 remote machines with development hardware connected to it.

We need to get status of who is logged in into machine or if machine is free to make some tests on hardware. We are using Microsoft Stack (MS Teams, Skype, 365 Pro plus etc).

I was thinking about Microsoft Teams BOT which would be checking remote PC status but I dont know if that's possible.

I know that Get-WMIObject can be used to check who is currently logged in but i dont think that it would be possible from Azure where this BOT would be running. I think that it would require to create some kind of telemetry service on remote PCs also to send status to MS Azure so BOT can display proper status.

Does anyone know about such solution or had similar problem ( status of remote machine visible to team members). I would like to use MS stack so everyone could just see on Skype, MS Teams, Outlook who is using remote PC or is PC is free.

PS: we are working from home and connecting to enterprise network using VPN. Remote PCs are running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. A Bot running on teams cannot get the information of a system or the system hardware.